# Problems in migration from localhost to my online webserver of a WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I am finding some problems uploading a WP site from my local web server to the official online web server.

The situation is the following , on my local web server:

1. I have installed WP website on my computer
2. I have configured it
3. I have installed custom a template

After, I have uploaded this site in a folder on my official online web server. I have took the local database export and imported in the online database using PhpMyAdmin (to export the local database on a file and then to import it on the online database)

Finally I have changed the file **wp-config.php** changing the MySql connection settings and putting here the settings related to the official online database.

When I try to open the website it appears to me, here you can say how: http://www.scorejava.com/wordpress/

Ok...seems good but there are two problems:

1. **If you try to open an article it is not open the article on the online server but in the localhost server, infact open this URL: [code]http://localhost/wordpress/?p=81[/code]**
2. **If I try to open the administration panel opening this URL: [code]http://www.scorejava.com/wordpress/wp-admin/[/code] I obtain a white page**

I don't know if these two problems are related together but I think that all may depend due to a problem of location path...

I think that somewhere there is some settings that specify the URL (that can't be localhost...), but (if it is so...) where is this setting? in some file or in the database?

Some one have an idea? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Look into this:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

There's a link on there for a "[Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)" tool that's very handy (make sure to read the instructions and have a backup of the db before using it).  The problem is that image URL's and other things are stored in the database and will reflect the URL of the dev location.  That tool will go through and properly update all instances from the dev URL to the final location.

Normally before you move a WP site you also want to update the site URL in the General settings as well, which may be contributing to your second problem.